# Read lines from text file, check content fulfills criteria

Tags: c#, file, streamreader

Hey I'm pretty new to C# so I'm just experimenting with how I can utilise it to perform tasks.
I want it to go through a text file and make sure each line is correct, example format of the text file is:

```
;irrelevant
;ignored

table Driver
number 123
name Name123
chassis Mondeo
rank 1
race_image 100
body_style ccar
wheel_basename vauxhall
end

table Driver 
number 178
name Dan#178
chassis XJS
rank 1 
race_image 100 
body_style ccar 
end

table Driver
number 76
name Timmy76!
chassis Lexus
rank 1
race_image 100
body_style ccar
wheel_basename lexb
end
end
```

It needs to ignore blank lines, or lines with just a space in, and not be case sensitive. Whilst it's going through, after it checks each line I'd like it to display it on the console window so once it finds something incorrect it can show the user where the error is; so there'd be a constant stream of lines until it finds something wrong.

It needs to go through and check each section.

- If 'table driver' is present, check the next line, else stop and inform user
- Check 'number ' then check the actual number after is either 1 - 3 digits, else stop and inform user
- Check 'name ', actual name value after can be anything, else stop and inform user
- Check 'chassis ' actual chassis value after must be a specified string from a list, else stop and inform user
- Check 'rank ' then check actual rank number is from 1-10, else stop and inform user
- If 'race_image 100' is present, check the next line, else stop and inform user
- If 'body_style ccar' is present, check the next line, else stop and inform user
- The wheel_basename line is optional
- If 'wheel_basename'  is present, check value after is specified string from a list, else stop and inform user
- If 'wheel_basename' is not present, check the next line
- If there are 2 ends, each on a different row, then perhaps there'd be a 'goto' function and display a checking complete message
- If there's just 1 end, it needs to start the process again on the next drivers table

The code I've written at the moment skips lines starting with a semicolon like it's supposed to. But when I try to get it checking for 'table driver' it starts reading from the start of the text file again

```
using (StreamReader textFile = new StreamReader("Drivers.txt"))
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("Drivers.txt"))
        if (line.StartsWith(";"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            continue;
        }
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("Drivers.txt"))
        if (line.StartsWith("table driver", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
            // Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

Comment: It starts over again because you're using File.ReadLines a second time. Also please fix your indentation, you have some {} missing and it's pretty hard to follow.

Comment: `XML` would be better choice for you. Write the file in `XML`, it'll be easy to parse it

Comment: You have load the Drivers.txt 3 times. And also you haven't used the textFile variable.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, XML would make this easier however if changing your data source is not an option this can easily solved as-is.

Firstly, each time you start a foreach loop on file you are starting from the beginning. Once the inner loop finishes, the previous one would continue where it left off.

For example:
If you had the following code:

```
foreach(string loop1 in File.ReadLines("data.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("loop1: " + loop1);
    foreach(string loop2 in File.ReadLines("data.txt"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("loop2: " + loop2);
        foreach(string loop3 in File.ReadLines("data.txt"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("loop3: " + loop3);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the following Data Set:

```
one 1
two 2
three 3
```

your output would look like:

```
loop1: one 1
    loop2: one 1
        loop3: one 1
        loop3: two 2
        loop3: three 3
    loop2: two 2
        loop3: one 1
        loop3: two 2
        loop3: three 3
    loop2: three 3
        loop3: one 1
        loop3: two 2
        loop3: three 3
loop1: two 2
    loop2: one 1
    .... continued ....
```

As far as the parsing goes, a simple solution would be to put your logic within a switch statement. 
Example:

```
foreach(string loop1 in File.ReadLines("data.txt"))
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) 
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (line.Equals("end"))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    string[] parts = line.Split(" ");
    if (parts.Length != 2) 
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    switch(line[0])
    {
        case "one":
            if (!line[1].Equals("1"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR! One != 1");
            }
            break;
        case "two":
            ....
        default:
            //not recognized. Do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```